# Can you use the attach database command with a db stored remotely?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to store a database in different files and have each of these files stored in a different computer. Then from any of these computers I want to be able to access the other databases and attach them together with the command `ATTACH DATABASE` to create a single local database with all the information.

Is this possible or does ATTACH DATABASE require that the databases are stored locally?

Comment: Is it mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Mysql does not support attach database statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a file to *SQLite* as long as it's accessible on the filesystem. Both Unix and Windows can do that.

It is [strictly not recommended](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_filesystems_with_broken_or_missing_lock_implementations) to *write* anything to such remote-mounted database files. It should be OK for reading, though.

No idea about MySQL, but probably the same or stricter limitations apply.